# Load Custom Social Button For My Site Like Gplus or FB

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I'm trying to create a custom social button for my site that I want users to include on their site using the code below. Previously I was using `iframe` which works but it had design issues that may affect the site its placed on.

Previous button.php:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 50px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 60px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I4_1397562331199" name="I4_1397562331199" src="site.com/show.php" title="Button"></iframe>
```

The `button.php` I loaded using an `iframe` also, but the `iframe` I use to to load `button.php` needed a lot of things added to the iframe to maintain width so I would prefer to give users a simple line of code like below.

Now i want to use:

```
<script src="http://mysitehere.com/button.php?sid=6587652341GFDSY"></script>
```

What code can I use inside that php file `button.php` to basically load `show.php` which includes the button css and images? For `show.php` I will need to be able to append `?sid=` to it.

Answer (score 0):

What i wanted to do was basically load the button with the simple line below. 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mesitehere.com/button.php?sid=6587652341GFDSY"></script>`

Loading it like that rather than using iframe was a better option since it was lighter than having to use the iframe with custom style elements.

To accomplish what I wanted I simply put the contents of button.php in documentwrite like below. The code in button.php has the iframe with the proper styling and its basically just getting printed

`<?php
echo '
document.write(\'<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 50px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 60px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I4_1397562331199" name="I4_1397562331199" src="http://mysitehere.com/show.php" title="Button"></iframe>\');
';
?>`